# When a Wraith initially loses insubstantial from Radiant damage does it take full damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

In a recent battle I was DMing when the players were cleansing the temple in Gardmore Abbey, the players were attacked by a **Trap Haunt** which is a very wraith-like creature.

Wraiths are usually insubstantial and they usually lose that insubstantial trait when they are exposed to Radiant damage.

> **Insubstantial**
>   The [wraith creature] takes half damage from all attacks, except those that deal force damage.  Whenever the [wraith creature]
>   takes radiant damage, it loses that trait until the start of its next
>   turn.

But that begs the question, do Wraiths take full radiant damage from the initial hit, rather than half?

Comment: It has to take the damage before losing the insubstantial effect. This would imply it still takes half damage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

As Colin pointed out, it's **taking** radiant **damage** that causes it to lose insubstantial. Since losing insubstantial is not an Immediate Interrupt, it does not occur *before* the event that triggered it, but *after* it.

Basically, force attacks bypass its insubstantiality, radiant attacks help *other* attacks bypass its insubstantiality.